# Verilog Force - Release

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is it fine to force a signal twice before releasing it in verilog ? Something like below,

```
initial begin
  force top.dut.xyz.abc.dout = 1;
  #5ns;
  force top.dut.xyz.abc.dout = 0;
  #5ns;
  release top.dut.xyz.abc.dout = 0;
end
```

Which force gets released when we eventually release it ?

Thanks,
Badri

Answer (score 2):

There is only one force in effect for a signal at a time. In your case the second force will `replace` the first one in '5ns'. The `release` will completely  free the signal.

Answer (score 1):

In consecutive forces last one is the valid, the release command releases this last force